# How to use child component data in parent component? How to make a binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For example, we have one field Input, property 'currentNode' in child component and property 'activeElement' in parent component. Every time we change value in Input, it affects property 'currentNode'. And also, of course, parent component contains child component (I mean HTML).

So, I want that every time currentNode changes somehow, it affected activeElement, which's located in parent component.

Comment: Option 1: move both to parent. Option 2: provide a callback function as a prop that will be called every time `currentNode` is changed

Comment: This is called two-way binding, I've seen more than one person ask about it, so I just made a general QA for it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73178502/12914833. See that link for instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  **(change)=""** method into your Input field. Then Use **@Output()** to send the event on every change. While you emit **currentNode** in your parent. your parent  function automatically calls then you can update your parent **activeElement** with the emitting value

[click here](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component) to see How you can send data to your parent component

Comment: Thank you very much!) One more question: is there a way that we can combine decorators @Input() and @Output() for one property?
I mean, like: @Input(), @Output() someValue: int = 5;

Comment: @DenisBredun yes, https://stackoverflow.com/q/73178502/12914833

Comment: No, do it spritely