# Angular - How do I implement two way binding, binding parent property to child property and vise versa?

Tags: angular

If I have a parent component with a child component nested inside of it, how do I bind one of the parent's properties to one of the child's properties, so that changes to the child property are reflected in the parent and vise versa?

### Example

**Parent Component**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  values = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear', 'melon'];
  index = 0;
  parentProp = '';
  changeProp() {
    this.parentProp = this.values[this.index++ % this.values.length];
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Parent Property: {{ parentProp }}</p>
<button (click)="changeProp()">Change Parent Property</button>
<app-child></app-child>
```

**Child Component**

```js
export class ChildComponent {
  values = ['carrot', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'potato', 'broccoli'];
  index = 0;
  childProp = '';
  changeProp() {
    this.childProp = this.values[this.index++ % this.values.length];
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Child Property: {{ childProp }}</p>
<button (click)="changeProp()">Change Child Property</button>
```

As you can see, you can change the value of `parentProp` and `childProp` in their respective components. How do I make it so that both `parentProp` and `childProp` are always synchronized with the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Two Way Binding: https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

In the child component you decorate the property with `@Input()` to make it an input property. You also need an `EventEmitter` decorated with `@Output()` to emit the property back to the parent. You then emit the new value of the property whenever it is changed.

**The name of the `EventEmitter` must be the name of the input property suffixed with "Change"**

**Child Component TS**

```js
  @Input() childProp = '';
  @Output() childPropChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  changeProp() {
    this.childProp = this.values[this.index++ % this.values.length];
    this.childPropChange.emit(this.childProp);
  }
```

Now we can easily bind this variable to the parent using banana-in-a-box notation `[()]`

**Parent Component HTML**

```html
<app-child [(childProp)]='parentProp'></app-child>
```

Changes to the property in either component will be reflected in both components.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-en4ogt?file=src/app/app.component.html